# Batch Convert A .XML InfoPath File To .PDF Using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powershell-3.0, infopath2010

I have a number of .XML files that are created in SharePoint from a .XSN template in InfoPath Forms Services (not client).

I would like to archive these infopath forms to .PDF.

Is there a way to batch convert .XML files that were created using infopath forms services to .PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following approach to create PDF's from InfoPath docs.

1. Save InfoPath xml to SQL.  Use a table with a column that is the xml data type.  Make sure to create xml indexes
2. Create a view that uses SQL xquery to shred the xml as needed.  You'll use this view for your report.
3. Use SSRS or some other reporting tool to generate PDF's as needed.

You can batch the SSRS generation in PowerShell after the first two steps are completed.

Answer (score 0):

A Forms Services based InfoPath form can be opened in InfoPath, it is not limited to be used just in Forms Services.  Unfortunately Forms Services does not allow PDF output.

You could - painstakingly - write some code against the InfoPath client object model to suck all files out of SharePoint, convert them to PDF and then upload them again, or you could Google for 'PDF Converter for SharePoint' and download a product that can automate Infopath conversion from SharePoint workflows or a friendly web services API (that can be used from PowerShell).

You can find a free whitepaper on the topic of InfoPath PDF (and other format) archiving [here](https://twitter.com/muhimbi/statuses/364426918311256064). It discusses a number of solutions, some of them free, some commercial.

Disclaimer, I worked on this product so consider me biased. No direct link provided as StackOverflow frowns on linking to your own site.